# GoogleVR library not supporting 64-bit requirement from playstore

Tags: android, performance, android-gradle-plugin, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

I am using `GoogleVR` library to load panos in my app.

**Google VR Depencencies**

```
  implementation 'com.google.vr:sdk-base:1.160.0'
  implementation 'com.google.vr:sdk-panowidget:1.170.0'
```

and getting following `.so` files in my apk

[image]

Now i am unable to upload a new apk on playstore, and getting following error message.

> This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement.
>   The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but
>   they only have 32-bit native code: 30.

I also tried adding following line in gradle file, but nothing changed.

```
ndk {
    abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'armeabi'
}
```

Comment: 64 bit ARM ABI is `arm64-v8a`, you need to add this to your abiFilters (obviously you need to have the `arm64-v8a` folder with the correct `.so` files)

Comment: but `GoogleVR` sdk is not providing `.so` files for `-x86_64` architecture. I didn't add these `.so` files in libs folder, `com.google.vr:sdk` dependency added those`.so` files.

Comment: I was not referring to x86_64 binaries, i was referring to arm 64 bit ones (i don't work with Google VR but i'm pretty sure they provide ARM 64 bit binaries in their dependencies)

Comment: Yes they provide `arm64`, and i used that, but apk fails to upload on playstore because `google vr` is not providing `x86_64`

Comment: I've digged trough VR SDK aar and inside there are 3 ABI supported, `x86`, `armeabi-v7a` and `arm64-v8a`. If you use `abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'` it should works

Comment: @MatPag : Yes, but play store asks for `x86_64` `.so` files, and `GoogleVR` is not providing those.

Answer (score 1):

I find a "solution" for this issue. (Waiting to google fix this and provide a x64 support libs, not definitive)

Practically all mobiles use a ARM process, so this solution may not works in devices with x64 architecture, i not test

Basically to google let you to publish we create a x86_64 folder in the native libs folder(we have to find where is the native libs on our project) and copy the 32 bit .so files (in x86 folder)

Obviously this is not a definitive solution so is the best that i found to google allow me to publish app

Answer (score 0):

```
 ndk {
      abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'armeabi'
 }
```

You can try with remove abiFilters code.