# Is it safe if i only target armeabi devices and not x86 devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-gradle-plugin

I am using some external dependencies in my app, those apps have some `.so` files but those `.so` files are not available for `x86_64`.

So play store does not upload apk and give following error message.

> This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement

So i split apk and created following apks.

```
   splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include  'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a'
            universalApk false
        }
    }
```

If i upload these 2 apks, play store successfully uploads the apk.

Now my question is that is it fine to not upload x86 apk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's fine.

What will happen is that people with `x86` and `x86_64` devices will not find your app in the Play Store.

An exhaustive list of x86 devices can be took using gsmarena filter at this link: https://www.gsmarena.com/results.php3?sFreeText=INTEL&sOSes=2

> You can ignore x86 devices for now if your are not aiming at running your app in the default emulator/genymotion or x86 environments

Comment: Thanks MatPag, I read somewhere that last device released for x86 was for Jellybean OS, is it true?

Comment: No, it's not true. Some Zenfone were upgradable to Lollipop too. Like this one: https://www.gsmarena.com/asus_zenfone_5_a501cg_(2015)-7160.php (check the Platform section)

Comment: Thanks, can you also check this question asked by my colleague. 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/57587816/2541348

Answer (score 0):

Your app won't be accessible in Play Market for devices based on x86_64 architecture. But it's very unlikely because most of smartphones are based on Arm

Comment: Is there any way i can know which devices are x86 supported

Comment: There is no proved source. I have googled it and have not found they are common